# How can I set Kubernetes Cronjob to run at a specific min time?

Tags: kubernetes, cron-task

I would like to run the job at each 30 min + 2, such as 9:02 9:32 10:02 ... 
How to set this in `* * * * *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify minutes 2 and 32. so it would be

```
2,32 * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is an accepted answer already but I would like to explain a bit more on that topic.

You already know that you need a specific cron expression to be configured:

> A cron expression is a string comprising fields separated by white
>   space that represents a set of times, normally as a schedule to
>   execute some routine.

The easiest way to describe/generate it would be by using an online tool like for example [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html). There you can also find some Cron expression examples for better understanding of the topic.

So in your use case which is:

> to run the job at each 30 min + 2, such as 9:02 9:32 10:02

the expression would be: `0 2/30 * ? * * *`

which means:

```
Seconds Minutes Hours   Day Of Month    Month   Day Of Week Year
0       2/30    *       ?               *       *           *

At second :00, every 30 minutes starting at minute :02, of every hour
```

and results in:

```
Wed Feb 05 10:32:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 11:02:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 11:32:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 12:02:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 12:32:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 13:02:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 13:32:00 UTC 2020
Wed Feb 05 14:02:00 UTC 2020
```

and so on.

I hope that it makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as such

```
0 2/30 * * * ? *
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.